# Extract directory entry from archive

Tags: swift, xcode, unzip, zipfoundation

Is it possible to extract a directory entry from an archive? 
How can I do it?

Code to extract a file.txt from the archive:

```
let fileManager = FileManager()
    let currentWorkingPath = fileManager.currentDirectoryPath
    var archiveURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: currentWorkingPath)
    archiveURL.appendPathComponent("archive.zip")
    guard let archive = Archive(url: archiveURL, accessMode: .read) else  {
        return
    }
    guard let entry = archive["file.txt"] else {
        return
    }
    var destinationURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: currentWorkingPath)
    destinationURL.appendPathComponent("out.txt")
    do {
        try archive.extract(entry, to: destinationURL)
    } catch {
        print("Extracting entry from archive failed with error:\(error)")
    }
```

If as entry I use a subdirectory path of the zip file, can I extract that directory and all its contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ZIP archives don't store parent/child relationships for entries. An archive is a flat list of entries, that have a `path` property.
Because archives are organized as a list - and not as a tree - there is no efficient way to obtain a subtree.

In ZIP Foundation, `Archive` conforms to `Sequence`. So you can use `filter` to find all entries with a specific path prefix. e.g.

```
let entries = archive.filter { $0.path.starts(with: "Test/") }
```

You can then iterate over all qualifying entries and use the `extract` code from your question.
There are some edge cases to consider though:

- You will have to create (intermediate) directories yourself (e.g.
  with `FileManager.createDirectory(...)` during extraction.
- ZIP archives *don't* require dedicated `.directory` entries. The best approach is, to create the directory hierarchy "on-demand". (E.g. if you encounter an entry with a parent path that doesn't exist yet, you create it)
- There is no guaranteed order of entries. So you can't make any assumptions on already existing paths during extraction.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Thomas! And thanks for the amazing library! 
I'm struggling because I'm extracting something like 400 files (images and videos, more or less 300Mb in total) from a zip file and it takes 10 minutes to finish. I was wondering if extracting all the directory with that data was faster than extracting all the single files entry by entry. But as you explained I have to go through all the entries also to extract the parent directory.

Comment: Did you also measure extraction time with a release build. There is significant difference between `Debug` and `Release` builds.